# flashsocket on socketio and nodejs not working

Tags: flash, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to get flashsocket working with socket.io but it does not, always going in xhr-polling fallback.

I don't see what I'm doing wrong, if anybody can help.

**On server side** :

```
var app = express.createServer(),
io = require('socket.io').listen(app, {
    flashPolicyServer: true,
    transports: ['flashsocket', 'htmlfile', 'xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling']
});
app.listen(80);
```

**On client side** :

```
...
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
...
            socket = io.connect();

            socket.on('connect', function(evt) {
                console.log(socket.socket.transport.name);

                onOpen(timeDifference(new Date(), earlierDate), socket.socket.transport.name);
                earlierDate = new Date();
                socket.on('disconnect', function(evt) {
                    onClose(evt);
                });
                socket.on('echo', function(msg) {
                    onEcho(msg);
                });
                socket.on('error', function(evt) {
                    onError(evt);
                });
            });
```

After that I checked that my browser chrome has flash enabled.
I also checked that port 843 and 10843 are listening and responding :

```
<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

On the server log, only get :

```
debug - served static content /socket.io.js
debug - client authorized
info  - handshake authorized 14328044138726156
debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/xhr-polling/14328044138726156?t=1333755740295
debug - setting poll timeout
debug - client authorized for 
debug - clearing poll timeout
debug - xhr-polling writing 1::
debug - set close timeout for client 14328044138726156
debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/xhr-polling/14328044138726156?t=1333755740299
debug - setting poll timeout
debug - clearing poll timeout
debug - xhr-polling writing 5:::{"name":"echo","args":["transport type : xhr-polling; and socket.id : 14328044138726156"]}
debug - set close timeout for client 14328044138726156
debug - discarding transport
debug - cleared close timeout for client 14328044138726156
debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/xhr-polling/14328044138726156?t=1333755740303
debug - setting poll timeout
debug - discarding transport
debug - cleared close timeout for client 14328044138726156
debug - clearing poll timeout
debug - xhr-polling writing 8::
debug - set close timeout for client 14328044138726156`
```

Thanks for you help

Comment: Have you verified that the client is requesting and properly receiving the SWF file?

Comment: thanks for you question : yes I've checked : but the client is not even requesting this file. I also verified that the .swf can be accessed : it is.

Comment: to be more clear I checked : http://localhost/socket.io/WebSocketMain.swf : I have on the screen a nice "Welcome to socket.io."

Comment: and if I check http://localhost/socket.io/flashsocket/WebSocketMain.swf, than I get "Protocol version not supported." on the screen and the nodejs server showing "client protocol version unsupported". And on the previous check (localhost/socket.io/WebSocketMain.swf) I get on the server : "unhandled socket.io url"

Comment: You say the "the client is not even requesting this file". That sounds like the problem then, hard to make a flash socket without a flash object on the page. You may have to set `WEB_SOCKET_SWF_LOCATION`, see http://socket.io/#faq

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the problem. I tried, but no change, and no error in console. I use the 0.9.5 version of socket.io, the .swf file is served by node, and since 0.7 there is no need anymore to set this variable. When debugging in Chrome, I could check that in the socket.io.js the line 2642 "if ('undefined' == typeof window || window.WebSocket) return;" returns effectively. And thus the following lines are not executed. This lead to line 2588 to the FlashSocket.check function where "'__initialize' in WebSocket" is false, so FlashSocket.check returns false. Could you help ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact, it works !

Thanks to XHR, you lead me to more analyze and test so I could found by myself.

It works, but different as expected :
When websocket is enabled on a browser, you cannot use flashsocket instead.

So even if you setup the server with : `transports: ['flashsocket', 'htmlfile', 'xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling']` your google chrome will never use flashsocket because it has websocket  enabled and it falls back to xhr-polling.
But Internet explorer which doesn't have websocket enabled will use flashsocket.

And I have no need to setup socket.io without websocket so this behavior works for me.

Moreover I think this behavior is nice because it prevents loading heavy .swf files when you don't need them.

Jerome.